# EXCEL - Iterating over a table for multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm making a print job tracking excel and I'm trying to track how many pages of a particular size are printed in total. For instance, 10 total standard pages are printed, 13 Ledger size, etc.

Here's the basic idea:

[image: Print Job Tacking]

I've tried `VLOOKUP`, and `COUNTIF` and can't seem to get it right.

I thought that excel would have a function that could iterate over a table for multiple values multiple times, however I can't seem to do so. My next step was going to be trying VBA to achieve this.

Thank you for reading and any help.
Cheers!

Comment: Sounds like `SUMIF` is what you need, but hard to tell wihtout seeing sample data. I assume your image is the desired result. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54133435/edit) to show us what your data looks like?

Comment: I have updated the image to include the entire table, this should give a better idea for goal I have. 

I'll give SUMIF a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) formula for that.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my issue!